# name 'crs_matrix' is not defined

Tags: python, logistic-regression

Try to create new train matrix

```
X_train_sparse_new = crs_matrix(hstack((X_train_sparse, new_feat_train['year_month_scaled'].values.reshape(-1,1))))
```

but get error name 'crs_matrix' is not defined.
Anyway, I have imported it:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, hstack
```

and want to ran my own class:

```
def get_auc_lr_valid(X, y, C=1.0, ratio=0.9, seed=17):
   
    train_len = int(ratio*X.shape[0]) 
    X_train = X[:train_len, :] 
    X_valid = X[train_len:, :] 
    y_train = y[:train_len] 
    y_valid = y[train_len:]  
    
    logit = LogisticRegression(C=C, n_jobs=-1, random_state=seed) #объект логистическая регрессия, задействуем все ядра
    #передали то занчаений C, которое пришло вызовом из аргумента значений функции
    
    logit.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    valid_pred = logit.predict_proba(X_valid)[:, 1] #прогноз для отложеннрой части, который дает вероятности для Элис
    
    return roc_auc_score(y_valid, valid_pred)
```

for kaggle dataset https://www.kaggle.com/c/catch-me-if-you-can-intruder-detection-through-webpage-session-tracking2

Can you please help me to deal with crs_matrix, please

Expect to get matrix which I can use for my class

Comment: You imported `csr_matrix`, while you're calling `crs_matrix`. Switch the `r` and the `s`.

Comment: It's a simple misspelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just because of a small spelling mistake in,

```
X_train_sparse_new = crs_matrix(hstack((X_train_sparse, new_feat_train['year_month_scaled'].values.reshape(-1,1))))
```

swap r and s in `crs_matrix`.

Correct code is

```
X_train_sparse_new = csr_matrix(hstack((X_train_sparse, new_feat_train['year_month_scaled'].values.reshape(-1,1))))
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer, but for future reference: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366135/12567365) - "_The post is unlikely to be helpful for future users, so it doesn't help anyone if we keep it opened._" The typo has been clarified in comments made in the question.

Comment: You can also take the [tour], read [answer] and look at the various resources in the [help] for more guidance.